# Docker best practice scaling

Tags: node.js, docker, containers

I have an array with 1 million string type elements.
I have node.js application, and it deals with each string for API request to an external service.

I want to split that array, and run one nodejs container for each part of array.

Is there any idea how can I do that dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a producer-consumer scheme using a queue based approach. This is no the easiest approach but is an elegant and scalable solution.

You will have a producer (container) that queue items in a queue, and N consumers (containers) that subscribes the queue to get items and work with them.

With that you can easily scale out and in. You can see [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/#getstarted) a great queue server that support many languages.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way will be probably to use some container orchestration (native docker services as a quick solution or kubernetes) but overall logic is depends on the way how your node.js app takes string (will it be hardcoded to some config, passed as API call etc.) Probably it will be better to use docker node.js sdk (https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) and using it parse array and spin up containers.